# ODE in python with specific time point

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ode, differential-equations

I explain the question and reach the problem at the end of explanation.

In order to solve function `f` as an ODE with python,
at first we must set an initial point or initial condition (`x0=0.2`). Then, according to codes which I have searched on internet and sources, we should choose a range (time point) for solving that and plotting. For example `t=np.linspace(0,5,20)` which divides the range between `0` to `5` into `20` sections and we have 20 outputs.

```
    Sol=odeint(f,x0,t)
```

...
The problem is, I would like to have just one output at one time point, I set an initial point for example `x0=0.2`, now I want to have one answer at the specific point which I choose, for example at the point of `3.4`.
When we plot the ODE we have all answers from first point to final point, but I want to have optional choice to set an specific points instead of using `linspace(min, max,n)`

Comment: Without knowing exactly what your solver is doing, this will be hard to help with. Can you break down what odeint actually does (possibly a Runge-Kutta implementation)? Can you give an example function and input? Some kind of MWE would help.

Comment: Or as we call them here, a [mcve].

Comment: I added tags to give your question more context.  You need to give more of the calling code, including the relevant `imports`.  I guessed, for example, that you are using `scipy.integrate.odeint`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `t` argument can contain just two points, with the first element being the time value of `x0` (the initial condition), and the second being the final time that you are interested in.

```
t0 = 0
t1 = 123.45  # final time that you are interested in
sol = odeint(f, x0, [t0, t1])
```

Then the values at time `t1` are `x1 = sol[-1]`.

If the time span between `t0` and `t1` is long enough, the solver might make the maximum allowed number of internal steps before reaching `t1`.  That limit can be changed with the `mxstep` argument.

Comment: thank you so much my friend. This is exactly what I want, but could you tell me please? Why sol[-1] gives us the answer? What is it?

Comment: When you write `sol = odeint(f, x0, t)` and `t` is a sequence of time values, `sol` will have shape `(len(t), len(x0))`.  Row `k` of `sol` is the solution at time `t[k]`.  `sol[-1]` is the *last* row (that's how indexing works in python--negative values index from the end).  In this case, because `t = [t0, t1]`, there are only two rows in `sol`, and the solution that we want is the second row, so I could also have written `x1 = sol[1]`.

Comment: Once again I appreciate your help and your attention. For my last question, the out put is between two brackets, [ ]  how can i remove these brackets to have just a number.

Comment: If your differential equaiton is a scalar (not a system of equations), then you can write `x1 = sol[-1, 0]`.